# Throw IOException in multiple return results with Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm testing error handling. I want the first call to `mockedObject.foo()` to throw a new IOException, and the second to return bar. I tried the following code,

```
mockedObject.foo() >>> [{throw new IOException()}, bar]
```

But, when I run the test, I get an error stating that a closure cannot be cast to Bar,

> FooSpec$_$spock_feature_0_1_closure2 cannot be cast to Bar

How can I mock this behavior with Spock?

EDIT: After seeing the documentation referenced by tim_yates, I just changed the test to,

```
mockedObject.foo() >>> firstBar >> {throw new IOException()} >> secondBar
```

This comes close enough to testing what I needed to test. The following code threw the same exception, so I'm guessing Spock is setting the return type of the mocked method based on the first object return.

```
mockedObject.foo() >>> {throw new IOException()} >> secondBar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, a complete working example:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib:3.1') 
@Grab('org.ow2.asm:asm-all:5.0.3') 

import spock.lang.*

class MyTestSpec extends Specification {    
   def 'spec'() {
      given:
      def a = new A()
      a.b = Mock(B) {
         foob() >> { throw new Exception('aaa') } >> 1
      }

      when:
      a.fooa()

      then:
      def e = thrown(Exception)        
      e.message == 'aaa'

      when:
      def r = a.fooa()

      then:
      r == 1
   }
}

class A {

    B b = new B()

    Integer fooa() {
        b.foob()
    }
}

class B {
    Integer foob() {
        2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do:

```
mockedObject.foo() >>> {throw new IOException()} >> bar
```

([See here in the documentation](https://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html#_chaining_method_responses))

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. Unfortunately, I got the same result with that code.

Comment: What does the method `foo()` under test look like?

Comment: 'foo()' isn't under test. The method under test is basically looping through calling foo and handling errors.

Comment: @Matt_Bro Make sure you match the parameters in `foo()` call. Safest would be to use as `mockedObject.foo(*_) >>> {throw new IOException()} >> bar` if you do not care about the parameters. note `*_` while mocking. If there is one parameter to foo then `mockedObject.foo(_) >>> {throw new IOException()} >> bar` should work

Comment: Looking at the documentation it looks like the triple right-shift operator is for an array of values. Chaining values ( exception closure, then bar) 'normally' should behave as desired.

Comment: This throws the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to split the 'then' block:

then:
1 * mockedObject.foo() >> {throw new IOException()}

.... (some other invoke assertions)

then:
1 * mockedObject.foo() >> bar.

I know this topic is old, but maybe somebody still wants to find the solution for it.
(Spock test: throw exception or value based on Invocation Order)
Please refer to : https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.0/interaction_based_testing.html
Invocation Order part